# SVN find out merged revision?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

Some developers  in mine team did check-in's in branch_A. Same revisions were required to be merged to branch_B also. Developers did manually(not using svn merge) 
merge some of revisions in branch_B but not all revisions. Now i need to find out which revisions has been merged and which are not .

Is there a way svn can help here ? If there is no way, can i find out what are the changes (at file level) under branch_A which are not in under branch_B?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just making a checkout of branch_A, branch_B and use a tool do compare this folders like Beyond Compare.

Or you can use [svnlook changed](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html) or [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnlook.c.diff.html)